# Differential of an operator $\phi: Mat_{2 \times 2}{\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow Mat_{2 \times 2}{\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let's consider an operator $ \phi: Mat_{2 \times 2}{\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow Mat_{2 \times 2}{\mathbb{R}}$ so that $A \rightarrow A^{-1}$.

How to evaluate its differential? By the differential we denote the linear part of the function's difference, just like $f(x+h)-f(x)=L(x) \cdot h+ o(h)$

For instance, the same problem for $f: A \rightarrow A^{2}$ can be solved by the following approach: $f(X+H)-f(X)=(X+H)^{2}-X^{2}=XH+HX+H^{2}=L(x) \cdot H + o(H)$, according to the fact that $o(H^{2})=o(h), h \rightarrow 0$ (is it true?), we state that $L(x)=XH+HX$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation for $A\mapsto A^2$ is essentially right. It should be $L(X)H=XH+HX$ and $o(H^2)\neq o(H)$, however, $H^2\in o(H)$ and that suffices.

The inverse map is only defined on the open subset $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ of invertible matrices. To calculate the differential, you can use Neumann series:

\begin{align}(X+H)^{-1}&=(X(1+X^{-1}H))^{-1}\\
&=(1-(-X^{-1}H))^{-1}X^{-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (X^{-1}H)^n X^{-1}\\
&=X^{-1}-X^{-1}H X^{-1}+o(H)\end{align}
for invertible $X$ and sufficiently small $H$. Therefore, the differential is given by $L(X)H=-X^{-1}HX^{-1}$.
If you assume differentiabilty of $\phi$, this result can also be derived by noticing $I_2=XX^{-1}$ and using the Leibniz rule.